# sql server: Creating a ranked list by assigning weights

Tags: sql-server

I have a table `Survey` with 10 entries. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qwka9.png. 10 users had to submit a ranked list of items 1-5. 1 being most important. How can I write a query that can assign a weight to each column, count the number of times a item occurred in that column, and return a the 5 items in a ranked list 1-5 with its "score". Is this even possible with SQL Server?

So I guess +5 to each item for every time it occurred in column `Growth1`. +4 to for column `Growth2` etc.

Is that the best way to go about creating a ranked list?

Desired output: possible

```
1   Market Share                   45
2   Disease Profile Development    30
3   Physician Recruitment          28
4   Referrals                      21
5   Splitters                      18
```

Comment: Could you add some sample data and a desired result in text form to the question?

Comment: My actual data in whole is in the imgur link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 
ISNULL(b.count_1,0) + 
ISNULL(c.count_2,0) + 
ISNULL(d.count_3,0) + 
ISNULL(e.count_4,0) + 
ISNULL(f.count_5,0) DESC) AS rank
,a.categories
,ISNULL(b.count_1,0) + ISNULL(c.count_2,0) + ISNULL(d.count_3,0) + ISNULL(e.count_4,0) + ISNULL(f.count_5,0) AS total_score FROM

(SELECT DISTINCT Growth1 AS categories FROM [TESTDB].[dbo].[testtable]
UNION SELECT DISTINCT Growth2 AS categories FROM [TESTDB].[dbo].[testtable]
UNION SELECT DISTINCT  Growth3 AS categories FROM [TESTDB].[dbo].[testtable]
UNION SELECT DISTINCT  Growth4 AS categories FROM [TESTDB].[dbo].[testtable]
UNION SELECT DISTINCT  Growth5 AS categories FROM [TESTDB].[dbo].[testtable]) AS a

LEFT JOIN
(SELECT Growth1, COUNT(Growth1) * 5 AS count_1
FROM  [TESTDB].[dbo].[testtable]
GROUP BY Growth1) AS b
ON a.categories = b.Growth1

LEFT JOIN
(SELECT Growth2, COUNT(Growth2) * 4  AS count_2
FROM  [TESTDB].[dbo].[testtable]
GROUP BY Growth2) AS c
ON a.categories = c.Growth2

LEFT JOIN
(SELECT Growth3, COUNT(Growth3) * 3  AS count_3
FROM  [TESTDB].[dbo].[testtable]
GROUP BY Growth3) AS d
ON a.categories = d.Growth3

LEFT JOIN
(SELECT Growth4, COUNT(Growth4) * 2  AS count_4
FROM  [TESTDB].[dbo].[testtable]
GROUP BY Growth4) AS e
ON a.categories = e.Growth4

LEFT JOIN
(SELECT Growth5, COUNT(Growth5) * 1  AS count_5
FROM  [TESTDB].[dbo].[testtable]
GROUP BY Growth5) AS f
ON a.categories = f.Growth5
```

Comment: Is there an easy way to actually create a column with the ranks 1-5?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: I think use Row_Number() to basically turn the row numbers into a column with the values 1,2,3,4,5. Like my output example in my question.

Comment: I've appended the code so that it adds the rank to the result set.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the query by splitting it up in a few common table expressions;

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT 5 score, growth1 area FROM mytable
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 score, growth2 area FROM mytable
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 score, growth3 area FROM mytable
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 score, growth4 area FROM mytable
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 score, growth5 area FROM mytable
), cte2 AS (
  SELECT area, SUM(score) score FROM cte GROUP BY area
  HAVING area IS NOT NULL
), cte3 AS (
  SELECT area, score, 
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY score DESC) rank
  FROM cte2
)
SELECT rank, area, score
FROM cte3
ORDER BY rank;
```

cte1 basically just extracts the data from each column along with the associated score.
cte2 sums the score up by area.
cte3 ranks the total score per area.
The outer query just orders the result by rank.

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2efac/1).

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll use this. Anyway to add a parameter of where MainHospital = @MainHospital in this? MainHospital is a column in the same table

Comment: Can add declare @MainHospital varchar(50)='Hospital_1'; to the top.

Comment: @user3570283 You can either filter in cte1 by adding the `where` to each part of the union, or use `GROUP BY area, MainHospital 
  HAVING area IS NOT NULL AND MainHospital=@MainHospital` in cte2.