# sql-server: Invalid column name trying to add parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query and am trying to add a parameter of when it = `Hospital_1` under the column `MainHospital` from my table `Survey`. I'm getting a "invalid column name 'MainHospital'" within my `WHERE MainHospital = @MainHospital`. Everything is pulling from the same table 'Survey' and the column exists.

For more context see my last question here: [sql server: Creating a ranked list by assigning weights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24142872/sql-server-creating-a-ranked-list-by-assigning-weights/24143983#24143983)

```
    declare @MainHospital varchar(50)='Hospital_1';
         SELECT a.categories, 
        ISNULL(b.count_1,0) + ISNULL(c.count_2,0) + ISNULL(d.count_3,0) + ISNULL(e.count_4,0) +     ISNULL(f.count_5,0) AS total_score FROM

        (SELECT DISTINCT Growth1 AS categories FROM [DBNAME].[schema].[TABLENAME]
        UNION SELECT DISTINCT Growth2 AS categories FROM [DBNAME].[schema].[TABLENAME]
        UNION SELECT DISTINCT  Growth3 AS categories FROM [DBNAME].[schema].[TABLENAME]
    UNION SELECT DISTINCT  Growth4 AS categories FROM [DBNAME].[schema].[TABLENAME]
    UNION SELECT DISTINCT  Growth5 AS categories FROM [DBNAME].[schema].[TABLENAME]) AS a

    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT Growth1, COUNT(Growth1) * 5 AS count_1
    FROM  [DBNAME].[schema].[TABLENAME]
    GROUP BY Growth1) AS b
    ON a.categories = b.Growth1

    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT Growth2, COUNT(Growth2) * 4  AS count_2
    FROM  [DBNAME].[schema].[TABLENAME]
    GROUP BY Growth2) AS c
    ON a.categories = c.Growth2

    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT Growth3, COUNT(Growth3) * 3  AS count_3
    FROM  [DBNAME].[schema].[TABLENAME]
    GROUP BY Growth3) AS d
    ON a.categories = d.Growth3

    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT Growth4, COUNT(Growth4) * 2  AS count_4
    FROM  [DBNAME].[schema].[TABLENAME]
    GROUP BY Growth4) AS e
    ON a.categories = e.Growth4

    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT Growth5, COUNT(Growth5) * 1  AS count_5
    FROM  [DBNAME].[schema].[TABLENAME]
    GROUP BY Growth5) AS f
    ON a.categories = f.Growth5

    WHERE MainHospital = @MainHospital
    ORDER BY total_score DESC
```

I can't answer my own question but I figured it out. just added the where clause to each sub query.

```
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT Growth1, COUNT(Growth1) * 4 AS count_1
FROM  Survey
WHERE MainHospital = @MainHospital
GROUP BY Growth1) AS b
ON a.categories = b.Growth1
```

etc

Comment: I don't see any table Survey I only see [DBNAME].[schema].[TABLENAME].

Comment: ok then all of its from same table called [DBNAME].[schema].[TABLENAME].

Comment: If you replace @MainHospital with 'Hospital_1' and run the query in SSMS does it work? And what is the code calling this query?

Comment: @simon in my where clause? no it doesn't work, column is invalid. What code, my aspx?

Comment: What table is MainHospital a column of?

Comment: Survey. all of the [DBNAME].[schema].[TABLENAME] are the same table. Everything is pulled from the same table.

Comment: figured it out, see my updates.

Answer (score 0):

I put the `WHERE MainHospital = @MainHospital` within each join sub query.

```
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT Growth1, COUNT(Growth1) * 4 AS count_1
    FROM  Survey
    WHERE MainHospital = @MainHospital
    GROUP BY Growth1) AS b
    ON a.categories = b.Growth1
```

Comment: yes this looks like an answer, but some textual explanation about how it works would make it clearer.